# wkhtmltopdf not working with spring boot and docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, wkhtmltopdf

I am using java wrapper for wkhtmltopdf https://github.com/wooio/htmltopdf-java. Added following Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.woo</groupId>
  <artifactId>htmltopdf</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.8</version>
</dependency>
```

I have not separately downloaded the wkhtmltopdf tool. It works alright on local ubuntu machine by just adding the above dependency. Now when I deploy the same on a centos server using docker it gives the following error

```
"Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.woo.htmltopdf.wkhtmltopdf.WkHtmlToPdf"
```

My docker image file is

```
FROM FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

ARG WAR_FILE

# Install wkhtmltopdf
RUN apk add --no-cache wkhtmltopdf

WORKDIR /opt/tomcat

RUN echo "Copying $WAR_FILE to tomcat webapps"

# Add the main war file
COPY ${WAR_FILE} $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/dodo.war


# define the entrypoint
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "/opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh", "run" ]
```

Any reason as to why this is happening and how to resolve this? if there are any other dependencies that is need how do I add that to docker file?